# jquery carouFredSel - One pagination control for 2 sliders

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I used carouFredSel for my slider. I want to have only one control pagination.

Now I tried it but it doesn't work ^^

```
$("#pager2").click(function() { 
        $("#foo, #fooA").trigger( "pagination" ); 
    });
```

here what I have for now http://jsfiddle.net/f6cpk/

I found here only the "prev" and "next" button.
http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/caroufredsel/PM-820949

Help Please ^^

Comment: what do you mean with 'one control' ?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle so we can see the code working?

Comment: here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f6cpk/
the pagination of the first slider must also control the second slider. But in this part only the next and prev are only working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'synchronize' setting in the first carousel.

```
$("#foo").carouFredSel({
    synchronise: ['#fooA', false],
    rest of your settings...
});
```

Also make sure that both carousels have the same number of slides.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxM45/1/

http://docs.dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/custom-events.php